# Realtime client update on stored data change

Tags: c#, xbap, real-time-updates

I'm getting lost in all the options offered on the net and I don't know where to start.

Context : As a learning experience I want to build an online multiplayer card game (think about it as a poker game). People log-in and play together.

Need : Such application requires realtime capability because when a player decided to do something all the players around the table have to be notified of it. My question is about this need and I would like it to be as plug and play as possible.

Stack : I'm using XAML Browser Applications because its the closest to what I know (C#, XAML, MVVM). Database still have to be decided.

The options I have found on the internet for doing so are : 
- Firebase realtime database: Looks plug and play but also looks expensive. 
- MongoDB replica change .watch() function: Looks like an option but I'm not interested in learning NoSQL for now.
- RethinkgDb: Is an abandoned project.
- WebSockets, socket.io, ... : Another set of scripts that could fail.
- SignalR : Looks interesting but not sure if it works with XBAP.
- Hasura / GraphQL / Postgresql engine: Looks interesting. 
- ...

How would you do to achieve realtime clients update with the following constraints: easy, free, as live as possible, XBAP compatible,... ?

Answer (score 1):

I will invite you to look at Redis, and its PUB/SUB feature.

It allows you to easily create communication channels and push messages to many subscribers, so a perfect fit for your need; it is very simple to put in place.

You can look at the [Pub/Sub documentation](https://redis.io/topics/pubsub).

I am not familiar with XBAP applications, but since it is browser-based, maybe you can use Web sockets to communicate with your server to push and consume messages, you can find a basic example using Javascript [here](https://github.com/tgrall/redis-websockets-vue-notifications).